# Tagged Logging with Class and method

Tags: ruby, logging, activesupport

I want to log using the Ruby Logger but with the classes and methods that are in the call stack.

Things I have tried:

1. `ActiveSupport::TaggedLogger`
2. `Kernel#caller` and `Kernel#caller_locations` - only seems to give me the file and line number
3. `TracePoint`

Has anyone done something like this or have different ways to use the above?  I was thinking there might be something with `Binding` that might have some information.

Example scenario:

```
logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
class A
  def initialize
    @b = B.new
  end

  def call_b
    b.meth_name('hello world')
  end
end

class B
  def meth_name(val)
    logger.log_with_classes val #made up method name
  end
end


A.new.call_b
"[A#call_b][B#meth_name] hello world" 
=> nil
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming this is a Ruby on Rails question since you mentioned ActiveSupport::TaggedLogger?

Comment: It is not.  I was just adding in the active support gem with out the full Rails framework.